# SCTP ABORT INIT in some version ubuntu

Tags: java, server, client, sctp

My sctp client cannot connect to sctp server in some version ubuntu ( 16.04 lts, 18.04 lts) but  work well in ubuntu 17.10 or centos 7.Server send ABORT chunk as response on INIT. i tried  both netty sctp lib and sun sctp lib for sample server and client but it same result "allways abort init" . command sctp_darn to create server and client is working normal in all version i tried.
 [file pcap here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ALBWsVT_gZBjrU4kTyNsUgJmx3AACdr/view?usp=sharing)
Can someone please help me ? Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add VM arguments -> Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true and then start the program